# CF10 AES encrypt java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B error when storing data

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, aes, coldfusion-10

Using CF10 AES-256 (AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding algorithm) I'm trying to store the encrypted string in a MySQL column (BLOB) and getting this error:

java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B

I've tried the default UU and base64 encodings and get the same error (semi-related - any advantages to storing in base64 over UU or vice versa?).

My code right now is just a simple test update query.  I've tried setting the cfsqltype to both blob and varchar on my cfqueryparam (and I've tried no cfqueryparam).

Here's my code where I have it now after suggestions from Jason.  I'm stuck on getting the decrypted string back though.

```
<cfset thePlainText = '010101939393923490 this is my string to encrypt'/>
<cfset theKey = application.sec.AESKey256/>
<cfset theAlgorithm  = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" />
<cfset theEncoding  = "base64" />
<cfset encryptedString = toBinary(encrypt(thePlainText, theKey, theAlgorithm, theEncoding)) />

<cfquery name="upd" datasource="#myds#">
  UPDATE table SET
    field = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#encryptedString#"/>
   WHERE id=1
</cfquery>
```

After that it's all well and good.  I have a blob field in the db and it's storing the data.  So now if I want to select it back I'm hitting a snag:

```
<cfquery name="qry" datasource="#myds#">
  SELECT field
    FROM table
   WHERE id=1
</cfquery>
```

I thought this would work:

```
<cfset decryptedString = decrypt(toString(qry.field), theKey, theAlgorithm, theEncoding)/>
```

But I'm getting "An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: The input and output encodings are not same"

If I dump the encrypted string var and the qry query the encrypted string vs. the dumped data are indeed different

SOLVED (toBase64 not toString)

```
<cfset decryptedString = decrypt(toBase64(qry.field), theKey, theAlgorithm, theEncoding)/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to store a string in a BLOB field.  ColdFusion's encrypt() method returns a string, not a binary object. So you can either store it in a VARCHAR instead or you can convert it to a binary object.

```
 <cfset cipher = encrypt("... blah blah blah") />
 <cfset binCipher = binaryDecode(cipher, "Base64") />
```

Then store binCipher.

Continue to use Base64 encoding in the encrypt() call.

Comment: Thanks Jason (btw read a bunch of your stuff so far this morning - great resources!)  Anyway - toBinary() works if I use base64 as the encoding.  But if I use the default UU encoding an error is thrown.  Is there an advantage of base64 over UU (other than it's working...)

Comment: Thanks! toBinary() expects a Base64 encoded string. So that is the advantage (and the reason for using Base64).

Comment: @Steve - base64 is better, but just FYI you can decode UU encoding with [binaryDecode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fc5.html).

Comment: I added code examples to the original - I'm having issues decoding the encrypted string now that I can store it without error.

Comment: @Steve - Do not use `toString`, use `binaryEncode(theEncryptedBytes, "base64")`.

Comment: @Leigh Ah, I see. I was looking at an older version of the LiveDocs (CF8) which required Base64 encoding.

Comment: @Steve Also, for future reference, if you have a follow up question you should post a new question to SO. Because now my answer, which is marked as correct, does not answer the new question that you asked and someone that come in search of an answer to the new question will have to dig into the comments to see Leigh's answer.